# Query to retrieve sum for each distinct Customer with varied Date ranges

Tags: sql

I have a database(CustomerTranscactions) which has a list of customer transactions whenever they buy something. I would want to know "Total value" (sum) of what they have bought for a specified date range, but the problem here is the date range is different for each customer.

I would like to provide this custom data range in the "where" clause something like (001, '2015-06-28','2016-03-31') for each customer id OR dump it in a separate temp table. (Will have anywhere about 70-100 customerIds when i run it eeach time)

CustomerTransactions table has the below columns
1. CustomerId,
2. TransDate,
3. ItemId,
4. Quantity,
5. Discount,
6. Value,

Kindly help

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please post your table's schema so we can actually be informed about what fields exist and what data types they are. Also what have you tried? SO is not here to do your work for you... So you should probably make an attempt at doing this work yourself before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one

SELECT CustomerId,
SUM (Value)
FROM CustomerTransactions
where TransDate > start date and TransDate